# php for statement is working only once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, for-loop, while-loop

here is my problem,

i have a php FOR statement, and whatever i do, it goes only ONCE through it... i check my vars into it, and write them to be sure... everything seems ok... BUT it never works...

here is the code ($user is initialized with my session var):

```
for($i=0;$i<=($size);$i++){
    $test = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `test`(`val`) VALUES ('IN!!')");
    $test->execute();
    $name = '';
    if($i==0){
        $name = $db->quote("test");
    }else{
        $name = $db->quote("number $i");
    }
    $number = $db->quote($i);
    //insert
    $query = "INSERT INTO `test`(`name`,`number`) VALUES ($name,$number)";
    $insert = $db->prepare($query);
    if($insert->execute()){
        $id = '';
        $get = $db->prepare("SELECT last_insert_id();");
        $get->execute();
        foreach($get as $myId){
            $id = $myId[0];
        }
        if(!(isRel($db,$user))){
            if(!(setIsRel($db,$user,1))){
                $error = false;
            }
        }
        if(!(hasRel($db,$etabId))){
            if(!(setHasRel($db,$id,1))){
                $error = false;
            }
        }
        if(!(buildRelationShip($db,$id,'2'))){
            $error = false;
        }
        if(!(buildRelationShip($db,$id,'3'))){
            $error = false;
        }

    }else{
        $error = false;
    }
    $check1 = '';
    $check2 = '';
    $check3 = '';
    $check4 = '';
    if(is_numeric($size)){
        $check1 = "OK";
    }
    if($i<=$size){
        $check2 = "OK";
    }
    $test = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `test`(`val`) VALUES ('SIZE IS NUMERIC? $check1 -- I SMALLER? $check2')");
    $test->execute();
}
```

ANSWER IS :

```
IN!! SIZE IS NUMERIC? OK -- I SMALLER? OK
```

Where am I wrong...?

Thanx for help !

(this PHP code is called from an .ajax request -jquery- but i don't think it has something to do with that because i already did some similar stuff with this...)

The SIZE var is always set to 2 or 3, never less! already checked

EDIT :

Well,

here is the code just before the FOR statement :

```
function createStages($db,$user,$size){
    $error = true;
    $size= intval($size);
```

i don't thing it'll help..

Comment: What is your `$size` value? I think that `$size` is `0`.

Comment: Sidenote: `VALUES ($name,$number)` - `$name` is most likely to be anything other than an `int`, so quote it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe that's what `$db->quote()` does.

Comment: my "insert" statement works fine... i add something in EDIT at end of my post if it helps ;)

Comment: @Julo0sS no, it didn't help. Post code before `for` loop to see how is `$size` set. Try `var_dump($size);` before `for` loop.

Comment: Is the `val` column a unique column? Maybe it's just inserting the same value every time through the loop.

Comment: Well, i set it manually within a .fancybox item... i already tried to write it in my DB within the insert statement, AND its value IS always what i decide to define... 3, 4, it doesnt change anything, i'm always OUT of my for statement after first loop... thats the reason why i check if my SIZE is_numeric or not... and.. IT IS... @Barmar : no it is not a unique column ;)

Comment: Since you're using ajax, can you echo $size right before the loop ends and verify its bigger than 0 ?

Comment: Why do you set `$error = false` when the `INSERT` fails?

Comment: @Barmar *"Maybe that's what `$db->quote()` does."* - You could be right.

Comment: why not replace $size with an actual number and see if it loops more than 1 time

Comment: Your answer doesn't include any `name` and `number` values. I think `$insert->execute()` is failing every time through the loop. What does `echo $query` show?

Comment: well! it becomes interesting... seems like the problem is coming from the INTVAL thing... what i receive into SIZE var is a "string"... what i send to my function is '3' or even "'3'"... i thought the intval would change it into an integer since i check it with IS_NUMERIC and it returns me TRUE... BUT it seems like it's not true anyway because, AS @FunkDoc SAID, if i put 3 manually... (somewhere before the FOR i set : $size = 3; ... IT WORKS... so... where am i wrong..? ^^ help!

Comment: @Barmar : my insert works fine... i have my value written into my db...

Comment: FYI, `is_numeric()` returns true if the argument is a string that looks like a number.

Comment: If the original value of `$size` is `"'3'"`, with extra quotes around it, `intval($size)` will be `0`.

Comment: `intval()` returns the integer at the beginning of the string. Since that string begins with a quote, not an integer, it returns zero.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your type conversion is getting messed up then. Remove the $size = intval($size), and replace the condition in the for loop with $i <= (int) $size.

Comment: it is almost it... just before i sent my $size var to my function, i was doing a $db->quote() on it... that's why my variable was used as a STRING and not as an int... THANX @Everyone for help! (PROBLEM SOLVED)